# Error: expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found" with Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm following the tutorial "Node.js: Test Driven Development" on inLearning and, after completing the tutorial, I still receive:

```
user data
✓ should have +1 user count after saving
user web
1) should have +1 user count after saving


1 passing (67ms)
1 failing

1) user web
   should have +1 user count after saving:
Error: expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"
  at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:268:12)
  at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:283:11)
  at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:173:18)
  at assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
  at /home/ubuntu/workspace/TestDrivenDevelopment/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:128:5
  at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:718:3)
  at IncomingMessage.parser (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:906:18)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Using the SuperTest framework, we are testing the user web API. I checked the node_modules directory and made sure that the supertest and co-supertest were both present.

I compared my code to the tutorial and it is identical, except for

```
var app = module.exports = koa();
```

which has changed since 2015, so it has to include new

```
var app = module.exports = new koa();
```

What might be causing this?

There are four files total.

user-api-spec.js

```
require('co-mocha');
var should = require('should');
var data = require('../user-data.js');
var fs = require('co-fs');
var api = require('../user-web.js');
var request = require('co-supertest').agent(api.listen());

before(function* (){
 yield fs.writeFile('./users.json', '[]');
});

describe("user data", function(){
   it("should have +1 user count after saving", function* (){
     var users = yield data.users.get();

     yield data.users.save({name:'John'});

     var newUsers = yield data.users.get();

     newUsers.length.should.equal(users.length + 1);
 });
});

//USER WEB TEST w/ SUPERTEST FRAMEWORK
describe('user web', function(){
 it("should have +1 user count after saving", function* (){
     var users = (yield request.get('/user').expect(200).end()).body;

     yield data.users.save({name:'John'});

     var newUsers = (yield request.get('/user').expect(200).end()).body;

     newUsers.length.should.equal(users.length + 1);
 });
});
```

user-web.js

```
var koa = require('koa');
var router = require('koa-router')();

var app = module.exports = new koa();

var data = require('./user-data.js');

router.get('/user', function* (){
 this.body = yield data.users.get();
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000);
```

user-data.js

```
var fs = require('co-fs');

var userFile = './users.json';

module.exports = {
 users : {
    get: function *() {
        var data = yield fs.readFile(userFile, 'utf-8');
        return JSON.parse(data);
    },
    save: function *(user) {
        var users = yield this.get();

        users.push(user);

        yield fs.writeFile(userFile, JSON.stringify(users));
    }
  }
}
```

users.json

```
[{"name":"John"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Status 404 means, your mocha test cases request don't connected with your main server so far, it's hitting somewhere else. Or check in your package-json are you mentioned test: 'mocha' in as command? then

I would suggest you to create an simple get api and return some values and then make an test case with mocha and console that.